# Replace string by excluding some strings in Java

Tags: java, regex

How can I replace following string in Java:

```
Sports videos (From 2002 To 2003) here.
```

**TO**

```
Sports videos 2002 2003 here.
```

I have use code but it remove the whole string   i.e.
    I am getting this ouput: `Sports videos here.`

```
String pattern= "\\((From)(?:\\s*\\d*\\s*)(To)(?:\\s*\\d*\\s*)\\)";

String testStr = "Sports videos (From 2002 To 2003) here.";

String testStrAfterRegex =  testStr.replaceFirst(pattern, "");
```

What is missing here?

Thanks

**DIFFERENT STRING WITH DATE FORMATTER**

If above string has date formatter like(`\\`) or any other character/words then digit, the answer will not work

I replace orginal answer with this pattern and it will work

```
String pattern= "\\((From)(.*)(To)(.*)\\)";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change to

```
    String pattern= "\\((From)(\\s*\\d*\\s*)(To)(\\s*\\d*\\s*)\\)";
    String testStr = "Sports videos (From 2002 To 2003) here.";
    String testStrAfterRegex =  testStr.replaceFirst(pattern, "$2 $4");
```

---

There are two problems:

**First**

You put `(?:)` in groups with years. This is used to not remember these groups.

**Second**

You don't use group identifiers, like $1, $2.
I fixed using $2 and $4 for 2th and 4th groups.

---

**EDIT**

Cleaner solution:

```
    String pattern= "\\(From(\\s*\\d*\\s*)To(\\s*\\d*\\s*)\\)";
    String testStr = "Sports videos (From 2002 To 2003) here.";
    String testStrAfterRegex =  testStr.replaceFirst(pattern, "$1$2");
```

Comment: Where I can learn for group identifiers.? Also What about If I want to replace "TO" with - (dash). i.e. Sports videos 2002- 2003 here.

Comment: I found myself 
String testStrAfterRegex =  testStr.replaceFirst(pattern, "$2 - $4");

Comment: @NETQuestion: Hi, you can learn more here http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html